# ASP .NET MVC OWIN and ADFS 3.0 with saml 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, saml-2.0, adfs

I am trying to understand how I can use OWIN (katana) with ADFS 3.0 as an IdP using a SAML 2.0 token. 
When you setup the relying party registration with your application you have an option of using the WS-Federation and or the SAML 2.0 token [image: Relying party registration]

From what I understand the SAML 2.0 token is the newer standard than WS-Federation. I believe one of the big differences is that you do not have to do any back channel validation of the token that you get back from your IdP but as far as why I have no idea. Can someone help me understand the following?

1. What are the differences from using WS-Federation and SAML 2.0?
2. If SAML 2.0 is better then how do I use OWIN to get that to work?

Comment: > *SAML 2.0 token is the newer standard than WS-Federation* And still outdated compated to OAuth2 with JWTs. In fairness OAuth2 is not for SSO persay.

Comment: Yeah from what I've read saml 2.0 and ws fed are the only options when using adfs as an idp

Comment: I'll just put this out there as a tool to help: https://github.com/CrescentFresh/Owin.OAuth.Adfs I'm not saying it solves your problem but it's a building block. Helped integrate our openidconnect implementation with a customer's crappy AD FS 3 setup.

Answer (score 8):

SAML-P 2.0 (P for protocol) uses SAML 2.0 tokens. WS-Fed uses SAML 1.1 tokens.

Both protocols implement federation. Historically, WS-Fed is Microsoft (SharePoint, CMS, Office 365) and SAML is open-source (Java).

Neither is "better" or "worse" functionally. It depends on your use case and what your IDP supports.

In terms of OWIN, there is no Microsoft OWIN SAML stack for this. There are others - refer [here](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html). Kentor is a popular choice.

If you have a choice, use WS-Fed. There is an official Microsoft NuGet [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation). Also, fewer parameters to configure.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. So you can use kentor in place of ws fed and then when you setup relying party registration you use the saml 2.0 web sso protocol?

Comment: Yes - Kentor uses SAML-P 2.0.